# How to change the default plotting color in matplotlib - spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, spyder

I am using `matplotlib` in `Spyder` for a simple plotting of sine and cosine. When i run this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.1)   # start,stop,step
y1 = np.sin(x1)
z1 = np.cos(x1)
plt.plot(x1,y1, z1)
plt.show()
```

I get this plot.

[image]

I didn't like the default plotting colors I am getting as you see in my plot above. However, I wanted to change them with good looking colors. I tried it with `plt.style.use('classic')` as the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('classic')

x1 = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.1)   # start,stop,step
y1 = np.sin(x1)
z1 = np.cos(x1)
plt.plot(x1,y1, z1)
plt.show()
```

But this again seems to add grayed background outside of the wall as you can see it and besides it seems to shrink the space of the plot lines to touch the X axis and this seems to be a bit odd.

[image]

Is there any elegant way of doing this in `matplotlib` without the grayed background outside the plot and without shrinking the space?

Comment: `plt.plot(x1,y1, 'b-')` will plot blue line, `g-` will plot green line, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were quite a few changes when matplotlib upgraded to version 2. Using `plt.style.use('classic')` changes back to the defaults before this upgrade. Some examples are a change in background colour and the addition of default x and y axis margins which can be seen in the two plots in the question.

The colour cycle was also changed in matplotlib versions 2 and above. Reading the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-in-default-property-cycle) shows you how to change the colour cycle back without affecting other parameters such as the background colour:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from cycler import cycler
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(color='bgrcmyk')
```

Your code would look like:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from cycler import cycler

mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(color='bgrcmyk')

x1 = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.1)   # start,stop,step
y1 = np.sin(x1)
z1 = np.cos(x1)
plt.plot(x1,y1, z1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But this gives another error `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'`. Did you try to run it?

Comment: @Brown I've updated the answer with the code I ran and the result I get

Comment: Thanks and I have marked it as an accepted answer. You can also do me a favor by upvoting the question :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped :-) and well done for a good first question!

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.1)   # start,stop,step
y1 = np.sin(x1)
z1 = np.cos(x1)
plt.plot(x1,y1,'blue')
plt.plot(x1,z1,'red')
plt.show()
```

Note, you don't have to do everything in a single plot - you can `plot` multiple times and they'll all be shown at a same time with `show`